# MySQL select query taking too much time

Tags: mysql, spring

I have a simple spring JPA select query which is taking too much to execute .

Table contains **~34 million** records.

```
Query : select * from temp where cust_id=211313131;
taking time >1sec
SLow Query logs : Query_time: 0.990815 Lock_time: 0.000034 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 3273885 Rows_affected: 0
```

```
Table structure : 

mysql> desc temp;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                                         |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| id          | bigint       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment                                |
| cust_id     | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                                               |
| amount      | double(11,3) | YES  |     | NULL              |                                               |
| is_enabled  | int          | NO   | MUL | 1                 |                                               |
| created_at  | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED                             |
| updated_at  | timestamp    | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Index on table :

```
mysql> show index from temp;
+-------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name                   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| temp        |          0 | PRIMARY                    |            1 | id          | A         |         285 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| temp        |          1 | idx_subscribers_cust_id    |            1 | cust_id     | A         |         281 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| temp        |          1 | idx_subscribers_is_enabled |            1 | is_enabled  | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| temp        |          1 | idx_subscribers_updated_at |            1 | updated_at  | A         |         264 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+-------------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.21 sec)
```

I have checked with explain, as explain result show it should execute immediately.

```
mysql> explain select * from temp where cust_id="31231234343";
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type | possible_keys           | key                     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      |    temp     | NULL       | ref  | idx_subscribers_cust_id | idx_subscribers_cust_id | 403     | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Can any one help me to find out why it is taking >1sec to fetch the record even index is present on that column.

Comment: how query is build ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suspicion related with implicit type conversion.

If query looks like this:
`select * from temp where cust_id = 1`,
then mysql try to convert column to fit type of parameter. Internally query is executed like this:

`select * from temp where cast(cust_id as UNSIGNED) =1`

I'm not sure about exact numeric type MYSQL converts to, but quite sure, that for this condition no existing key will be used

Comment: It is due to cust_id type mismatch. Cust_id is varchar and index is  also working for varchar input. but i was providing long value as in input thats why index is not used here

Comment: Great Reference : https://makandracards.com/makandra/14955-mysql-will-not-use-indexes-if-you-query-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE cust_id=211313131
```

Either change `cust_id` to be numeric (such as `INT UNSIGNED), or change the test to a string:

```
WHERE cust_id = "211313131"
```